# case and quotation in scheme & racket

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

I was a bit surprised by this racket code printing `nay` when I expected `yeah`:

```
(define five 5)
(case 5
  [(five) "yeah"]
  [else "nay"])
```

Looking [at the racket documentation for case](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/case.html) makes it clearer:

> The selected clause is the first one with a datum whose quoted form is equal? to the result of val-expr.

So it's about quotation. I'm pretty sure that I did not yet fully grasp what quotation in lisps can buy me. I understand it in the viewpoint of macros and AST transformation. However I'm confused why is it helpful in the case of `case` for instance..?

I'm also curious, with this specification of `case`, can I use it to achieve what I wanted to (compare the actual values, not the quoted value), or should I use another construct for that? (`cond`, while strictly more powerful, is more verbose for simple cases, since you must repeat the predicate at each condition).

Comment: `case` uses `memq`, which in turn uses `eq?`, you cant use that with numbers.

Comment: I think quotation is the problem, not `eq?`? `(eq? five 5)` => `#t`

Comment: Sorry, my bad! what is tested is `(eq? 5 'five)`, so if you `(case five [(5) ...` it will work as expected. Edit: Think of case as a `switch` type statement in other languages. Cases are constants.

Comment: hmm `(eq? '5 five)` is indeed true (which honestly surprises me) and so the inverted case does indeed work as you point out. I still don't understand why is `case` based on quotation and if I can "abuse" it (is it abuse?) for my purpose.

Comment: It is almost certainly indeterminate whether `(eq? 5 five)` is true or not, or equivalently whether `(eq? ’5 five)` is.  But Racket uses `equal?` for `case` anyway (Scheme uses `eqv?`).

Comment: It is not indeterminate, it will be true as long as `5` is between (- 2^30) and (2^30 - 1), I think, which is when it can always be represented by a [fixnum](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/numbers.html#%28tech._fixnum%29). The problem isn't `eq?` or `eqv?` or `equal?`, the problem is `quote`

Comment: @AlexKnauth Does Scheme even have a notion of a fixnum?  CL does, but it is still explicitly indeterminate as to whether `EQ` (which is `eq?`) compares any numerical type as `=` (and there have historically been cases where numerically-equal small integers *didn't* compare as `EQ`).  My point was that it's never right to use the object-identity predicate on numbers, of any type.  (I'm presuming that by 'the problem being quote’ you mean '... in `case`), as it should not be surprising that quoting numbers just yields the number...)

Comment: @tfb, I had assumed that this was in racket since the OP linked to the racket documentation, but even then you're right about `eq?` being the wrong thing for numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `case` introduces *implicit* `quote` forms, which cause your example to work for `'five` (whose value is `'five`), instead of `five` (whose value is `5`).

I almost never use `case` because of exactly this problem. Instead I use racket's [`match`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/match.html) form with the [`==`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmatch..rkt%29._~3d~3d%29%29) pattern:

```
(define five 5)
(define (f x)
  (match x
    [(== five) "yeah"]
    [_ "nay"]))
(f 5) ; "yeah"
(f 6) ; "nay"
```

This produces `"yeah"` on only the value `5`, just like you expected. If you wanted it to return `"yeah"` when it's equal to either `five` or `six`, you can use an `or` pattern:

```
(define five 5)
(define six 6)
(define (f x)
  (match x
    [(or (== five) (== six)) "yeah"]
    [_ "nay"]))
(f 5) ; "yeah"
(f 6) ; "yeah"
(f 7) ; "nay"
```

And if you really want to match against `quote`d datums, you can do that by writing an *explicit* `quote` form.

```
(define (f x)
  (match x
    [(or 'five 'six) "yeah"]
    [_ "nay"]))
(f 5) ; "nay"
(f 6) ; "nay"
(f 7) ; "nay"
(f 'five) ; "yeah"
(f 'six) ; "yeah"
```

These `quote` forms are implicit and invisible when you use `case`, lurking there waiting to cause confusion.

Comment: thanks that's helpful. still wondering if there are situations when `case` is the best choice, but currently leaning towards no. I'll leave the question open a bit longer because of that, if there'll be no answer, I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: There's also `evcase` in the `mzlib/etc` library, but it's a legacy library

Answer (score 3):

The Racket documentation gives this grammar:

```
(case val-expr case-clause ...)
```

where

```
case-clause     =       [(datum ...) then-body ...+]
                |       [else        then-body ...+]
```

Let's compare to your example:

```
(define five 5)
(case 5             ; (case val-expr
  [(five) "yeah"]   ;    [(datum) then-body1]
  [else "nay"])     ;    [else    then-body2])
```

We see that `(five)` is interpreted as `(datum)`. This means that `five` is 
a piece of data (here a symbol), not an expression (later to be evaluated).

Your example of case is evaluated like this:

First the expression `5` is evaluated. The result is the value `5`.
Now we look at a clause at a time. The first clause is `[(five) "yeah"]`.
Is the value `5` equal (in the sense of `equal?`) to one of the datums in `(five)`? No, so we look at the next clause: `[else "nay"]`. It is an `else`-clause so the expression `"nay"` is evaluated and the result is the value `"nay"`.
The result of the `case`-expression is thus the value `"nay"`.

Note 1: The left-hand sides of `case`-clauses are datums (think: they are implicitly quoted).

Note 2: The result of `val-expr` is compared to the clause datums using `equal?`.  (This is in contrast to Scheme, which uses `eqv?`.

UPDATE

Why include `case`? Let's see how one can write the example using `cond`:

```
(define five 5)
(let ([val five])
    (cond 
      [(member val '(five))      "yeah"]
      [(member val '(six seven)) "yeah"]  ; added 
      [else                      "nay"])
```

This shows that one could do without `case` and just use `cond`.
However - which version is easier to read?

For a `case` expression it is easy to see which datums the value is compared to.
Here one must look closely to find the datums. Also in the example we know beforehand that we are trying to find the value among a few list of datums. In general we need to examine a `cond`-expression more closely to see that's what's happening.

In short: having a `case`-expression increases readability of your code.

For the historically interested:  https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-mail/HTML/rrrs-1986/msg00080.html   disussed whether to use `eqv?` or `equal?` for `case`.

UPDATE 2

I'll attempt to given an answer to:

> I'm still not clear on the quotation vs working simply on the values though. 
>   I'm wondering specifically why doing the quotation, why working on datum instead 
>   of working on values. Didn't get that bit yet.

Both approaches make sense.

Let's for the sake of argument look at the case where `case` uses expressions rather than datums in the left hand side of a clause. Also following the Scheme tradition, let's assume `eqv?` is used for the comparison. Let's call such a 
case-expression for `ecase` (short for expression-case).

The grammar becomes:

```
(ecase val-expr ecase-clause ...)
```

where

```
ecase-clause     =      [(expr ...)  then-body ...+]
                |       [else        then-body ...+]
```

Your example now becomes:

```
(define five 5)
(ecase five
  [('five) "yeah"]
  [else    "nay")
```

This doesn't look too bad and the result is what we are used to.
However consider this example:

```
(ecase '(3 4)
  [('five (list 3 4) "yeah"]
  [else              "nay")
```

The result of this would be "nay". The two lists resulting from evaluating the expressions `'(3 4)` and `(list 3 4)` are not equal in the sense of `eqv?`.
This shows that if one chooses to use `eqv?` for comparisions, having expressions available on the left hand side won't be helpful. The only values that work with `eqv?` atomic values - and therefore one could just as well use implicit quotations and restrict the left hand side to datums.

Now if `equal?` was used it would make much more sense to use expressions on the left hand side. The original Racket version of `case` was the same as the one in Scheme (i.e. it used `eq?`) later on it was changed to used `equal?`. If `case` was designed from scratch, I think, expressions would be allowed rather than datums.

The only remaining issue: Why did the authors of Scheme choose `eqv?` over `equal?` for comparisons? My intuition is that the reason were performance (which back in the day was more important than now). The linked to post from the rrrs-authors mailing list gives two options. If you dig a little further you might be able to find responses.

Comment: yes I understand, but I wonder why `case` is defined like that, based on data as opposed to expressions? What use cases does it help with?

Comment: thank you! I'm still not clear on the quotation vs working simply on the values though. I'm wondering specifically why doing the quotation, why working on datum instead of working on values. Didn't get that bit yet.

Comment: thanks a lot, much clearer now! Does confirm that `case` is a little flawed in racket (if it was designed from scratch, it would be designed differently), will try to migrate to `match` rather, as suggested by Alex Knauth.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a reference right now, but `case` statements use literal, unevaluated data in their different clauses because it is both a frequent use-case and more easily subject to efficient compilation. 
You could probably write your own version of Clojure's [`condp`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/condp) macro or a custom conditional operator to handle your use case.

Comment: "it's a frequent use case" can you give an example where it's more handy to have quoting in `case` than not? Also, I know scheme is minimal, though racket less so, but still surprised there's no builtin operator for that? what's the idiomatic way here?

Comment: @EmmanuelTouzery Anytime you need to dispatch a runtime value against a set of statically known values, which happens often enough that an operator such as case exists in all other languages.

Comment: how is that related to quoting?